# Python - printing on the same line after using format string

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, format

My current code is:

```
for i in range(len(phoneList)):
    print("|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(formattedPhoneList[i],namesList[i],number[i], lastDue[i]))
    if float(lastDue[i]) > 850:
        print("**")
    elif float(lastDue[i]) < 850 and int(number[i]) > 350:
        print("++")
    else:
        continue
```

Desired Output would be:

```
|Index[0] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[0]|384|$ 976.97|**
|Index[1] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[1]|132|$ 188.81|
|Index[2] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[2]|363|$ 827.48|++
```

Current Output:

```
|Index[0] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[0]|384|$ 976.97|
**
|Index[1] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[1]|132|$ 188.81|
|Index[2] of formattedPhoneList|Name Index[2]|363|$ 827.48|
++
```

I have tried inserting a trailing comma and import stdout with no success. Is there another way to format this? Thank you for reading.

Comment: @Alik I've tried using their stdout method but I believe this issue is different because of the format before the if statement. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: `format` is a string function. It doesn't affect `print` in any way. Try to use `end` parameter of `print`

Comment: @Alik Sorry, I'm still quite new, where would I use ends parameter of print?

Comment: add it to the first call of `print`

Comment: I've tried doing this  print("|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(formattedPhoneList[i],namesList[i],number[i], lastDue[i]), end="") but the output format is randomly aligned with the second line having many spaces inbetween and the third line attaching itself to the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to do this:

```
for i in range(len(phoneList)):
    if float(lastDue[i]) > 850:
        extra = "**"
    elif float(lastDue[i]) < 850 and int(number[i]) > 350:
        extra = "++"
    else:
        extra = ""
    print("|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(formattedPhoneList[i],namesList[i],number[i], lastDue[i], extra))
```

Comment: This works splendid. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that it will skip the special cases if `lastDue[i]` is exactly `850`.  Perhaps you might want to change the first comparison to `>=` or the second to `<=` ?  I don't know enough about the intent to know which makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable

```
for i in range(len(phoneList)):
    data = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(formattedPhoneList[i],namesList[i],number[i], lastDue[i]))
    if float(lastDue[i]) > 850:
        data += " **"
    elif float(lastDue[i]) < 850 and int(number[i]) > 350:
        data += " ++"
    print data
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!